# handle json - ajax error with a proper fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have a user.json file on a web server that returns to

```js
{
 "name” : “ivana”,
 “age” : “27”
}
```

then I do:

```js
var user = $.ajax({
      url: pathsample.com/user.json,
      data: { format: 'json' }
});
```

How do I handle error properly, for just in case if user.json returns to 
“dfhsdfkjahfjd” instead of the proper object array (aka parsererror), or if the web server is down, etc?
(I’d like to actually pass an empty object array {} if my user.json returns to error. Is that possible?)

I saw a lot of posts doing something like this:

```js
var user = $.ajax({
      url: pathsample.com/user.json,
      data: { format: 'json' },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        or
        console.log(exception);
      }
});
```

But I don't care with what went wrong, I know it's because my json file is "dsafsadfasf" instead of {"name" : "ivana", etc}. How do I update my error to an empty array when my json file is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle success to set `user` variable from the callback with the correct data otherwise `user` will be empty object, success scenario is 1; error scenarios is many so by handling success any other failure happen will gurante empty object:

```
var user = {}
$.ajax({
  url: pathsample.com/user.json,
  data: { format: 'json' },
  success: function(data) {
    user = data
  }
});
```

Comment: Did that, but doesn't seem to work.. and when I console on error             `error: function(data) { console.log(data); }` it returns to `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "dsfgsMFJDSLFKHA DJKHFDJLKFJVADSLKFJ KLADSJFLKA↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}` => responseText is the dummy content that should be an array or to be replaced an array.

Comment: @ivanasetiawan did you notice in my code i handle `success` not `error` we not care for error as it will always result to empty object.

Comment: yea I put that on sucess, but the code still doesn't work so I console what the error returns to..